# Sorting through unlisted array using binary search?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, search, time-complexity

If I have an unsorted array and I need to find a certain element without switching them up I'd usually use linear search. But what if I decided to sort the whole array using quick sort or merge sort and then using binary search find the element I wanted to find, after that I'll just rearrange the array to how it was on the start. What would be the time complexities and space complexities of this and would it be more efficient with larger data sets than linear search?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that would not help to improve the time complexity. The bottleneck would be the sorting which (without any available assumptions about the data) has a *O(nlogn)* time complexity, which is worse than the linear time complexity you get when doing a linear search through the unsorted array.

Even if you have the kind of data for which a radix sort would be suitable, and get a sorted array with a linear time complexity, that still would not improve on the time complexity you already had with the naive search.

Without any extra information, you cannot do better than a linear time complexity. You can easily grasp this when you realise that *any* slot in your array could hold the element you are looking for. So in the worst case, it will be the last slot you look at, after having inspected all other *n*-1 slots in the array. Hence, you performed *n* operations, which represents a linear time complexity.

As you also asked about space complexity: sorting can be done in-place, so there is no impact on space complexity if you still decide to sort your data.

Comment: So is there any faster method than linear search

Comment: No. See addition to answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sorting and then searching every time something needs to be looked up, the whole operation takes O(nlogn) which is worse than O(n) for a linear search.

OTOH, if the contents of the list never change (or very infrequently change), you can get away with keeping a sorted copy at the beginning and then running all searches on the copy.

You can achieve O(logn) searching for changing lists, if you're list is implemented as a sorted data structure (usually a [binary search tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-balancing_binary_search_tree)), though you're list operations like adding and removing to the list become O(logn) as well. Java's TreeSet/TreeMap uses that.